# Tar command saves file in working directory instead of specified directory

Tags: bash, backup, tar, snapshot

I'm trying to make a automatic backup via the tar command:

```
datum=$(date +%F)
buweek=backup_$datum
snap=snapshot_$datum

mkdir /home/user/BackupArchiv/$buweek
tar -czvg /home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/$snap -f backupfull /home/user/BackupArchiv/$buweek
```

For some reason the backup file gets saved in my working directory, next to the script I execute, instead of the given directory.

Edit: Snapshot file now gets created

Comment: Be careful.You are not using `tar` but rather `gtar` and gtar is known to be unable to do incremental restores in case that more than trivial changes appeared between two incremental backups.

Comment: You don't have to manually edit the title. Just mark an answer as accepted. ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the argument after option -f is the output path and filename of tar command - citing `man tar` :

```
Common options:
       -C, --directory=DIR
              change to directory DIR

       -f, --file=ARCHIVE
              use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

so your correct command should look like:

`tar -czvg /home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/$snap -f /home/user/BackupArchiv/$buweek.tar.gz`

or maybe switch the paths since it's unclear what you want to backup and where you want it to end up - my example will generate a file:

`/home/user/BackupArchiv/backup_2020-10-08.tar.gz` for today :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've noticed that I confused the last two parameters "backupfull" and the following path. I've changed the command to: "tar -czvg /home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/$snap -f /home/user/BackupArchiv/$buweek/backupfull.tag.gz /home"  and the backup worked but tar still gave me the helpful response "tar: finished with errorstatus because of previous error" which I'm unsure what it means.

Comment: well glad you've fixed it. followup problem is not related to the original question so .. maybe raise another question with complete terminal output I guess.

Comment: I asked the new question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613687/tar-confusing-error-messages