# Tar confusing error messages

Tags: backup, tar

I'm trying to create an automated backup file using the tar command.

```
tar -czg /home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/snapshot_2020-10-09 -f /home/user/BackupArchiv/backup_2020-10-09/backupfull.tar.gz /home
```

After the script executes this command, it gives me a bunch of error messages and stops even though it isn't supposed to. Most error messages tell me about not having the right to access certain files, but these three are throwing me off:

```
tar: remove leading / from member names
tar: remove leading / from hard link targets
tar: exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

(I hope I translated all of these correctly) I'm not sure what is wrong with the command and visiting pages about these errors didn't really help either.

Edit: The other error messages I'm talking about where about files from another user I created. I somehow can't access these, and I'm unsure what I could to fix this.
Another thing I noticed was that the backup had problems with the backupfiles themselves since they get changed during the command. But I don't think there's any possible solution to that.

Comment: There should be more errors from `tar`; these two are warnings, and should not make `tar` exit with an error status.

Comment: Be careful! You are not using `tar` but rather `gtar` and the problem with your specific usage is that `gtar` is unable to do incremental restores if the differences betweem two incremental backups are more than trivial. This is caused by the insuffucient meta data for that purpose in the archive. This is a real problem since people usually do not run restores, but when you need it, it fails.

Comment: @schily so how do I fix it then? This command only gets executed once so doesn't even create any incremental backups (I delete the snapshots every retry)

Comment: @Kävin Why then do you use `gtar` and this option at all?

Comment: @schily because it's part of my task and after I create the full backup I need to automatically create an incremental back up each day using cron

Comment: I send you an answer to your last comment. Either stackexchange crashed and lost content or someone removed my last comment...

Comment: try using root user to tar the files that you do not own - see if it helps. I assume since you're trying to use incremental tar with journal file specified as `/home/user/BackupArchiv/snapshots/snapshot_2020-10-09` you need to have this journal file outside of directory you're trying to backup.

Comment: @Kävin trying to rewrite my disappeared comment: `gtar` cannot reliably restore incrementals, see various reports on this portal. Since I assume that you are creating backups to be able to restore them when needed, I recommend `star`. Fetch a recent `schilytools` version and look at the documentation for incrementals: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html the documentation for incrementals currently starts at page 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors with permissions are breaking the creation of incremental tar archive specified with `-g` .

Here's my point:

Without permissions to read the whole dir content:

```
$ tar -czg ./incremental_file -f ./backupfull.tar.gz /tmp
tar: /tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: /tmp/systemd-private-43e2279e55a349ceadf346b4d247d0a7-colord.service-sitmvL: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: /tmp/systemd-private-43e2279e55a349ceadf346b4d247d0a7-rtkit-daemon.service-pJ6qty: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

with (root) permissions:

```
$ sudo tar -czg ./incremental_file -f ./backupfull.tar.gz /tmp
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /tmp/.ICE-unix/1445: socket ignored
tar: /tmp/.ICE-unix/1629: socket ignored
tar: /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: socket ignored
tar: /tmp/.X11-unix/X1: socket ignored
tar: /tmp/ssh-Vp6I2M0cTcci/agent.1629: socket ignored
$ ls *tar.gz -alh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 644 Oct 13 09:33 backupfull.tar.gz
```

with non-root permissions:

```
$ mkdir bkp_dir
$ touch bkp_dir/bla
$ touch bkp_dir/bla2
$ touch bkp_dir/bla2
$ touch bkp_dir/bla3
$ touch bkp_dir/bla4
$ touch bkp_dir/bla41
$ tar -czg ./incremental_file -f ./backupfull.tar.gz ./bkp_dir
# tar exited OK creating archive
```

Comment: That is not the main problem. The main problem is that `gtar` is unable to restore incremental backups if the differences are non-trivial. DO you really like to make backups that cannot be restored?

Comment: yes @schily that's a good point and the OP should reconsider the backup strategy all-togather. Either switch to full backups of `tar` if he has to use tar or to use some mature backu solution - such as bacula/bareos or BackupPC (or million others... :) )

Comment: Are you shure that bacula does not use the incremental system from `gtar`? What I have in mind id that bacula has it's own multi-volume  management, so it does not depent on the defective multi-volume management in `gtar`, but it uses `gtar`s incrementals.